# Tank bullet shooting

Tags: 2d, transformation

Ok, I'm having a lot of trouble understanding using Matrices for Movement in a 2D game. I currently have a Tank object that has a Matrix3 globalTransform managing the direction Scale and Rotation. That Object is the Parent to a gun Object that rotates around the centre of the Tank.

That uses a localTransform that is multiplied by its parents globalTransform to get its own globalTransform. The Update Method is:

```
localTransform = localTransform * rotation;
globalTransform = tank->globalTransform * localTransform;
```

How would I go about implementing a bullet being shot from the Gun? Should I create a Bullet Object? What would be the math be to fire in a linear direction the way the gun is facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I would create a separate `Bullet` object in global coordinate space.

I guess you know how to transform a point from the gun's coordinate system to the global coordinate system. A simple way to get a global direction vector works like this:

```
// Coordinate system of the gun
Vec3 gunStart        = Vec3(1, 0, 1); // Local starting point of the bullet (tip of gun)
Vec3 gunTarget       = Vec3(2, 0, 1); // Local target vector

// Transform to global coordinates
Vec3 globalStart     = gun->globalTransform * gunStart;
Vec3 globalTarget    = gun->globalTransform * gunTarget;
Vec3 globalDirection = normalize(globalTarget - globalStart);
```

The bullet would spawn at `globalStart` and move in direction of `globalDirection`.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you press key for the shot then create bullet object.
2. Of course. You need to create class for your bullet.
3. So you must to have two variables which will remember the direction of the  bullet.